# Get the row from where foreign key is pointing at - mysql

Tags: mysql, select, foreign-keys

Now i have this table where `redirect` is an inside foreign key to `id`

```
id  name  redirect
 1   a      null
 2   b      null
 3   c      null
 4   d       1
 5   e       3
```

I only have `name` at the beginning and i need this query => `If redirect is not null then get the new name from where redirect is pointing at.`

for instance: if i have `a` at the beginning, do nothing because redirect is null. but if i have `d` at the beginnig go to where `id = 1` and get the `a`

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.redirect
WHERE t2.name = 'd'
```